# MySQL restore lost data after update from 5.7 -> 8.0.11

Tags: mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

I have a docker-compose file where I use the official `mysql:latest` image as my database server.

After a `docker pull mysql` and a `docker-compose up` the image updated from **5.7 -> 8.0.11**

**This update corrupted all my mysql data.**

All `.frm` files got deleted.

When I try to restart the mysql-server I get the following error, even with `innodb_force_recovery [1-6]`

```
2018-06-05T19:19:14.624533Z 0 [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Table flags are 0 in the data dictionary but the flags in file ./ibdata1 are 0x4000!
2018-06-05 19:19:14 0x7fd24a8b6740  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140541170509632 in file ut0ut.cc line 942
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
19:19:14 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
collection process might fail.

key_buffer_size=8388608
read_buffer_size=131072
-> Executing /opt/docker/provision/entrypoint.d/05-permissions.sh
max_used_connections=0
-> Executing /opt/docker/provision/entrypoint.d/20-nginx.sh
max_threads=151
-> Executing /opt/docker/provision/entrypoint.d/20-php-fpm.sh
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 68195 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000
mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2c)[0x55d85cb951ec]
mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x479)[0x55d85c4c3e59]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x110c0)[0x7fd24a4940c0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xcf)[0x7fd248c20fff]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x16a)[0x7fd248c2242a]
mysqld(+0x628387)[0x55d85c49a387]
mysqld(_ZN2ib5fatalD1Ev+0x12d)[0x55d85cd63c8d]
mysqld(+0xf9ead1)[0x55d85ce10ad1]
mysqld(+0xf9f108)[0x55d85ce11108]
mysqld(_Z6fil_ioRK9IORequestbRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_tmmPvS8_+0x2b0)[0x55d85ce1a230]
mysqld(_Z13buf_read_pageRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_t+0xce)[0x55d85cdcf1ee]
mysqld(_Z16buf_page_get_genRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_tmP11buf_block_tmPKcmP5mtr_tb+0x4aa)[0x55d85cd9e34a]
mysqld(_Z31trx_rseg_get_n_undo_tablespacesPm+0x143)[0x55d85cd41e23]
mysqld(+0x6274fb)[0x55d85c4994fb]
mysqld(_Z34innobase_start_or_create_for_mysqlv+0x2f3d)[0x55d85cd0ecdd]
mysqld(+0xd69f63)[0x55d85cbdbf63]
mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x4f)[0x55d85c50ebff]
mysqld(+0xb138e6)[0x55d85c9858e6]
mysqld(_Z40plugin_register_builtin_and_init_core_sePiPPc+0x2f0)[0x55d85c988ad0]
mysqld(+0x64a566)[0x55d85c4bc566]
mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0xc71)[0x55d85c4be121]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf1)[0x7fd248c0e2e1]
mysqld(_start+0x2a)[0x55d85c4b480a]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

I've searched for solutions how to restore data from existing `.ibd` files, but nothing works.

**What I've tried so far**

Since I have a local copy of the database, but with outdated data, I was hoping that I could re-import the data somehow.

**1. Tried to reconstruct the table and import the `.ibd` file into the tablespace:**

- Created a separate mysql instance
- `CREATE DATABASE new_db; USE new_db;`
- `CREATE TABLE wp_options(...)` to create the structure of the table based on my local dump that I have.
- `alter table wp_options discard tablespace`
- Copied the `wp_options.ibd` that I want to restore into the `new_db` folder
- `alter table wp_options import tablespace`.

On `5.7` it gives me the error:

```
ERROR 1815 (HY000): Internal error: Cannot reset LSNs in table `dnmc`.`wp_options` : Unsupported``
```

On `8.0.11` the server just crashes.

**2. Create tablespace and assign it to table**

I came across this one: https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/10/03/mysql-8-0-general-tablespaces-file-per-database-no-frm-files/

So I run:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE wp_options ADD DATAFILE "/var/lib/mysql/dnmc_orig/wp_options.ibd" Engine=InnoDB;
```

which gives me the following error, both on `5.7` and `8.0.11`.

```
ERROR 3121 (HY000): Incorrect File Name '/var/lib/mysql/dnmc_orig/wp_options.ibd'.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was finally successful restoring the data. My problem was, that I tried to restore the data with a `docker-compose`, which somehow didn't work.

So I took a different approach

**1. Run a docker image of `mysql:8` and mounted the "corrupt" folder to it**

```
docker run -d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -v /path/to/corrupt/folder:/var/lib/mysql --name mrestore mysql:8
```

The mysql-server started without any problems and I was able to run mysql with

`mysql -u root -p`.

But when I run the command `mysql>show databases;` It gave me an error like:

```
The user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does not exist
```

**2. Fix user does not exist error**

A quick google search led me to the answer of someone having the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49992868/mysql-errorthe-user-specified-as-a-definer-mysql-infoschemalocalhost-doe

Which is:

```
mysql -u root -p
mysql> SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown = 1;
mysql_upgrade -u root -p
```

**3. Dump databse**

Finally I was able to start mysql and dump the database that I thought I've lost

```
mysqldump -u root -p databasename > databasename.sql
```